# Change olMail.Body font name and font size if olMail.Body = str1 + str2

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code.

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String
Dim str4 As String

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = reviewer_email_id
olMail.Subject = "Task for Review"
olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
str1 = "Dear Mr. " & reviewer & ", " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see below details for review (Workbook attached)." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
str2 = "Task : " & title & vbNewLine & "Location : " & document_location & vbNewLine & "Start Date : " & start_date & vbNewLine & "End Date : " & end_date & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
str3 = "Await your Feedback." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
str4 = "Regards " & vbNewLine & assigned_to
olMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>str1 + str2 + str3 + str4</BODY>"

olMail.send
```

When this email is sent, it prints **str1+str2+str3+str4** as the output in Verdana font of size 10. And, when I remove the body tag and change `olMail.HTMLBody` to `olMail.Body`, it prints the values of str1, str2, str3 & str4 but no more font-size and family change.

I want to print the values which are stored in str1, str2, str3 & str4, not the variable names, but also want to change the font-family and size.

Is it possible to change the font-size and font-family of `olMail.Body` ?

The variables which i have concatinated using `&` are the values that I get from excel sheet. It is perfectly working fine. Only want to change the font-size and font-family to 10 and Verdana respectively.
Thanks.

Comment: `vbNewLine` means nothing in HTML, either use `<BR>` or `<P>`. Then `"<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & str1 & str2 & str3 & str4 & "</BODY>"`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by not putting variables outside double quotes to get their values.

Input:

```
"<tag>str1 + str2</tag>"
```

Output:

```
<tag>str1 + str2</tag>
```

In order to get values of variable (str1, str2, ...) inside mail body and keep formatting, you have to do this:

```
Dim str1 as String, str2 as string, str3 as String, str4 as String

str1 = "value1 "
str2 = "value2 "
str3 = "value3 "
str4 = "value4"

olMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 & "</BODY>"
```

Will produce:

```
<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>value1 value2 value3 value4</BODY>
```

Tested on Win10 and Outlook 2016.